# Appium java-client Throwing NullPointerException when building an Appium Service

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I am trying to create a `AppiumDriverLocalService` using a simple static method written on Java, as following:

```java
public class Bootstrap {

...

    private static AppiumDriverLocalService getAppiumService(File nodeFile) {
        return new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                .usingDriverExecutable(nodeFile)
                .usingAnyFreePort()
                .withIPAddress("0.0.0.0")
                .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(120))
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE)
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "debug")
                .build() // Here throws a NullPointerExcepetion
                ;
    }

   ...

    @BeforeAll
    public static void bootstrapApplication() {

        AppiumDriverLocalService service = getAppiumService(nodeFile);
    }
}
```

When I call `getAppiumService(nodeFile)` it is throwing a NullPointerException:

```bash
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:226)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:184)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.getLogOutput(DriverService.java:448)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:495)
        at br.com.alelo.qa.steps.Bootstrap.getAppiumService(Bootstrap.java:110)
        at br.com.alelo.qa.steps.Bootstrap.bootstrapApplication(Bootstrap.java:43)
```

My local infrastructure is:

- macOS 13.2.1
- node v18.17.1
- npm 10.0.0
- Appium Server 2.1.3
- Appium java-client 8.5.1

I do not know how to solve it.

I have already tried uninstall and reinstall all dependencies.

Help me, please?

Comment: This post solve my issue: https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/2004